# Is the 'after_save' hook fired when Lead is added via an API call in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am adding my Leads to SugarCRM via external API calls. Leads are added correctly. I need to do additional data handling around a lead, and pass it into a third party via API call, after a lead is added. I see the `after_save` hook - is that hook only triggered when a user is on the SugarCRM screen and saving, and would not be called when a Lead is added via an API?

If `after_save` hook isn't going to work for me when I add Leads via API, what hook would I use when adding code via my Extension code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

After some testing, when I pass in a new Lead into Sugar via an external API, the `after_save` hook is in fact being triggered. So you could use this hook and not worry that it only is fired when user is on the desktop module actually saving a record in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The `after_save` hook fires whenever the Bean (record) is saved on the server and should work just fine for your scenario.

It does not matter whether the call came from an API or even the cli/scheduler.
The browser application of Sugar 7+ also uses the API in the background, by the way.

---

However if you ever **do** want to have code customized for certain clients only, then you could use the [`platform`](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/9.0/Pro/Administration_Guide/Developer_Tools/index.html#Configure_API_Platforms) parameter (specified during client auth) to distinguish between them.
In older Versions of Sugar you don't have to predefine/"unlock" platforms - the client is allowed to just specify whatever they want. In current versions you have to add your custom platforms [via code](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Architecture/Extensions/Platforms/) or [via Administration](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/9.0/Pro/Administration_Guide/Developer_Tools/index.html#Configure_API_Platforms)

The default fallback platform is always `base`.
There are some other pre-existing platforms, e.g. `mobile` for the mobile app/version, `opi` for the outlook plugin, among others.

For customizations done in the `custom/clients` folder, it's usually enough to put the files in `custom/clients/<yourplatform>/` (instead of `custom/clients/base/`), using the same subfolder hierarchy within, in order to enable them for a certain client only. This can e.g. be used for [extending](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Extending_Endpoints/index.html)/overriding/wrapping api endpoints.